# Binding ItemsSource of Datagrid in a ContentPersenter

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am creating a UserControl that contain a ContentPresenter. I fill the contentPresenter in my window with a Datagrid, binding the itemsSource to a list, but it doesn't works.

My Datagrid is empty. But when I move the Datagrid out of my UserControl, i got data Inside.

**My UserControl**
XAML:

```
<UserControl Name="Instance" ...>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=AdditionnalContent, ElementName=Instance}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C# :

```
public Object AdditionnalContent
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionnalContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AdditionnalContent", typeof(object), typeof(MyUserControl),
      new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

**My Window**

```
<Window Name="win" ...>
    <Grid>
        <my:MyUserControl>
            <my:MyUserControl.AdditionnalContent>
                <!-- Datagrid is empty -->
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LIST, ElementName=win}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
            </my:MyUserControl.AdditionnalContent>
        </my:MyUserControl>

        <!-- Datagrid have content -->
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LIST, ElementName=win}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Object> LIST
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        fillList();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Download snoopwpf.codeplex.com. You can use this tool to inspect your UI while the application is running and discover binding errors.

Comment: I am on a computer at job and I am not admin, i can't install program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with this code

```
<Window Name="win" ...>
    <Grid>
        <my:MyUserControl>
            <my:MyUserControl.AdditionnalContent>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LIST, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
            </my:MyUserControl.AdditionnalContent>
        </my:MyUserControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I will not solve the answer now, cause i would like explaination about the reson.
I understand that it will try to find parent of parent to a window control, but it has been declare in the window, so why the binding don't see the windoe control by his name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is pointing to a property for a `Window` element which doesn't know what it is. The path that it only knows is the properties of the `Window`

Assuming your `LIST` is inside the `DataContext` of Window. You have to then explicitly point it to the `DataContext` of the `Window`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.LIST, ElementName=win}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Comment: I try your code, but it doesn't work. I edit my question to show C# code of window, wish it will help more.